# How can I group a time series according to the seasons using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a daily time series of sea surface temperature from MODIS/Aqua sensor, starting in 2002 until 2020:

```html
data['Image_Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Image_Datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data = data.set_index('Image_Datetime')
data.head()
```

[image]

I want to group all data correspondent to the summer period (December, January and February months), so then I can analyse just the temperature variations over a single season. I know this should be more or less simple, but I've been searching for a solution and none of them seems quite intuitive using only pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You must live in the southern hemisphere for summer to take place in December.

Try this:

```
season = data['Image_Datetime'].dt.month.map(lambda x: 'Summer' if x in [12, 1, 2] else 'Winter')

# Mean temperature by season
data.group_by(season)['Temperature'].mean()
```

Comment: Hi Code, thank you for your help. Yes, I live in the southern hemisphere :) Unfortunately when I try your suggestion I got a KeyError message relative to mine DatetimeIndex "Image_Datetime"

Comment: If you add the line after `set_index`, use `season = data.index.dt.month....`

Comment: Using `season = data.index.dt.month` I then got an **AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'**. Also tried to apply before setting the index, but the error persists